# getting request data from $http promise's response

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do some unit testing for an http request that I have. I post the data into the second parameter in my http post request

```
var data = {} /* some data object */;
return $http.post(url, data);
```

but then when I unit test, I cannot check if the data made it in.

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST(cfcmApiPath + 'book/addDocument').respond('IGNORE_ME');
var httpPromise = docComponentRestSvc.addDocumentToBook(22063, doc);
$httpBackend.flush();
```

This causes an error:

```
Error: Expected POST http://192.168.33.10/mymy/api/book/addDocument with different data
    EXPECTED: {"eventId":22063,"sequenceIndex":0,"name":"Nombre","type":"FRONT_OUTSIDE_COVER","value":"Que Tal, Amigo?"}
```

What's weird is that the call seems to be working when I run it normally. This is why I want to see what's up with the request data. However, I'm not sure how to do it. Any Advice?

For further details and probably related is that I have a 'core' library that I'm trying to implement where basically I want http from the library to be used because the library does some transformations and keeps things in the cache which does not seem to be automatically intercepted from the main module.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `response.data` in test or something else - depends on code that you are not shared with us.

```js
angular.module('document', [])
.service('docComponentRestSvc', function($http) {
  this.addDocumentToBook = function(data) {
    return $http.post('book/addDocument', data)
  }
})

describe('document component', function() {

  var $httpBackend, docComponentRestSvc

  beforeEach(module('document'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _docComponentRestSvc_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    docComponentRestSvc = _docComponentRestSvc_;
  }));


  it('POSTs new document', function() {
    var doc = {
     name: 'Nombre'
    };
    var mockResponse = 'IGNORE_ME';
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('book/addDocument').respond(mockResponse);
    docComponentRestSvc.addDocumentToBook(22063, doc).then(function(response) {
      expect(response.data).toBe(mockResponse);
    })
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

})
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```